# Quivers as noncommutative curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, noncommutative-geometry, quivers

I've heard that an idea behind noncommutative geometry (in dim 1) is to study "noncommutative" analogues of $\text{Coh}(\text{curve})$, rather than the curve directly. Apparently the category $\text{Rep}(Q)$ of f.d. representations of a finite quiver $Q$ is one such analogue (e.g. it's a one dimensional abelian category).

My possibly too hopeful question is- how far can you push this analogy? e.g.

- is there a notion of *genus* of a quiver $Q$?
- if $Q\to Q'$ is a map of quivers, is there a definition of *degree* of this map (and similar data like number of ramified points and their ramification degree, and a *Galois correspondence*)?
- are there elements in $\text{Rep}(Q)$ which are analogues of $\mathcal{O},\mathcal{T},\Omega^1$?
- what is the analogue of the global sections functor?

Comment: Derived categories of coherent sheaves vs derived category of quiver representations makes the analogy more precise. "Genus of a quiver" should probably be thought as zero as the Grothendieck group of $\mathrm{Rep}(Q)$ has no continuous part so "noncommutative Jacobian" is trivial. The other questions do not seem to allow for immediate categorical interpretation.